How to use a colon as a DMS separator in the QGIS layout coordinate grid
I need to format the display of the coordinate grid in the QGIS layout with the following structure: +DD:MM:SS,SSS (for northern and eastern hemispheres) and -DD:MM:SS,SSS (for southern and western hemispheres) . In other words, I need to use a colon to separate degrees, minutes, and seconds (without displaying °, " or '). I tried some grid customization solutions, unsuccessfully. Any ideas?

For more customization than replacing characters, see this post

A crude but simple option is to use a custom expression to simply replace the degrees and minutes symbols in the default D/M/S format that QGIS produces.
For example:
replace(to_dms(@grid_number,@grid_axis,3),array('°','′','″'),array(':',':',''))


(My regional format uses a period by default - I assume yours will use a comma. However, if required, you can add a replacement for this into the expression above.)

Thanks, Tom, it worked. In my case, I don't need the second symbol too, so i added another item in the array to exclude the ″:
replace(to_dms(@grid_number,@grid_axis,3),array('°','′','″'),array(':',':',''))
